# Find a Summation Formula for nCr

Tags: combinatorics, summation

There was a previous problem in my homework that basically demonstrated that:

```
10C7 = 9C6 + 8C6 + 7C6 + 6C6
```

And our question is:

```
"Use that fact to derive a summation formula involving expressions nC1."
```

I'm not entirely sure what this means, but I'm assuming we are to use Sigma.  This is what I came up with:

$${}_nC_r = \sum_{i=r - 1}^{n-1} {}_iC_{r-1}$$

I'm not sure if I'm even using legal notation here, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As an aside, your quoted equality is incorrect.  You are off by one as a result of missing the term `+ 6C6` on the right side.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to include that term, yes, you are correct.

Comment: As an additional aside, it is much more common to notate binomial coefficients as `\binom{n}{r}` which appears as $\binom{n}{r}$ so long as you have access to any sort of typesetting like we do here.  [Visit this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn more about how to type with MathJax and $\LaTeX$.

Comment: I'm familiar with this notation, just didn't realize that one was more common than the other.  I'll edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: @joe_04_04 If you prefer to stick with the written C, you could use `${}_nC_r$` ${}_nC_r$ or `${}_n\mathrm{C}_r$` ${}_n\mathrm{C}_r$

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula and try and prove the question,
$$\binom{n}{r}+\binom{n}{r-1}=\binom{n+1}{r}$$
Where $nCr=\binom{n}{r}$

> $$\sum_{i=r-1}^{n-1}\binom{i}{r}$$$$$$$$=\binom{r-1}{r-1}+\binom{r}{r-1}+\binom{r+1}{r-1}+\cdots$$$$$$as $\binom{r-1}{r-1}=\binom{r}{r}=1$$$$$$$\binom{r}{r}+\binom{r}{r-1}+\binom{r+1}{r-1}+\cdots$$$$$$$$\binom{r+1}{r}+\binom{r+1}{r-1}+\binom{r+2}{r-1}+\cdots$$$$$$$$\binom{r+2}{r}+\binom{r+2}{r-1}+\binom{r+3}{r-1}+\cdots$$$$$$$$\binom{r+3}{r}+\binom{r+3}{r-1}+\binom{r+4}{r-1}+\cdots$$$$$$$$\vdots$$$$$$$$\binom{n-1}{r}+\binom{n-1}{r-1}$$$$\binom{n}{r}$$

Comment: There are *much* simpler ways to prove the generalization than just repeated application of pascal's identity.  See the question I linked to in the above comments.

Comment: But it is easier to understand

Comment: Easier to understand than the following? "*To select $r$ numbers from $\{0,1,2,3,\dots,n-1\}$ you can break into cases based on the largest number selected noting that if the largest number selected was $k$ you could select the remaining numbers in $\binom{k}{r-1}$ ways.  Ranging over all possible values of $k$ gives the result*"